# Light scattering: Why is the natural frequency in air higher than the light frequencies?

Tags: visible-light, waves, scattering, frequency, air

In the [Feynman Lectures on Physics Vol. I Ch. 32 (Radiation Damping. Light Scattering)](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_32.html) it says:

> On the other hand, if we take the case of light in the air, we
>   remember that for air the natural frequencies of the oscillators are
>   higher than the frequency of the light that we use.

Why is that?

I could not find the answer elsewhere in the book.

Answer (score 1):

He is referring to the second paragraph of 31-3:

> However, we shall discuss the formula we have obtained, in various
>   possible circumstances. First of all, for most ordinary gases (for
>   instance, for air, most colorless gases, hydrogen, helium, and so on)
>   the natural frequencies of the electron oscillators correspond to
>   ultraviolet light. These frequencies are higher than the frequencies
>   of visible light, that is, $ω_0$ is much larger than $ω$ of visible light,
>   and to a first approximation, we can disregard $ω^2$ in comparison with
>   $ω^2_0$. ...

One reason why you would suspect this to be the case is that the orbital radius of an electron in a nitrogen or oxygen atom, which is on the order of $10^{-10}$ meters, is much smaller than the wavelength of visible light, which is on the order of $10^{-7}$ to $10^{-6}$ meters. Since the length scale of visible light is smaller, and frequency has an inverse relationship to wavelength, the frequency must be bigger.

Comment: How can one deduce a natural frequency (which depends on oscillator reset force, as far as I know, but I am no physicist) from the radius of the atom containing the electron?

Comment: It's basically just dimensional analysis. For the hydrogen atom, you have three dimensionful quantities: planck's constant,  the charge of the electron, and the reduced mass of the electron proton system (which is basically the mass of the electron), since the hydrogen atom can be treated non-relativistically. there is only one way to get a length and this length is the bohr radius. There is only one way to convert the length to a frequency and this gives you the oscillation frequency.

Comment: Now the conversion of this frequency to a wavelength involves the speed of light, which is a different speed from the speed you can form from planck's constant, electron mass and electron charge. However, the difference is only a factor of about 137, so the wavelength of light is not a half an angstrom but more like 10-100 nanometers, but this is still smaller than visible light.